# If $a_n \to a$ in $L^2$ and $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, does $\int F(a_{n_j}) \to \int F(a)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Suppose $a_n \to a$ in $L^2(\Omega)$. Let $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous with $F(0) = 0$. We have that $F(b) \in L^1(\Omega)$ if $b \in L^2(\Omega)$ and $|F'(x)| \leq C_1 + C_2|x|$.

I want to show$$\int_{\Omega}F(a_{n_j}) \to \int_{\Omega}F(a)$$
for a subsequence.

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you mean to write $F\circ b$?

Comment: I think that's the same as $F(b)$? right?

Comment: Does the domain $\Omega$ have finite measure? If not, $C_1$ is a problem: $F(x)$ could be $x$ for small $x$, and then $\int F(a)$ is not controlled by $\int a^2$.

Comment: Usually one uses $F\circ b$ or $Fb$ (especially for linear operators) for the composition of 2 functions. $F(b)$ normally denotes the value of $F$ at $b$, but considering what $F$ and $b$ are in your case, that's probably not what you were trying to say.

Comment: Does the theorem [quoted in this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/829707/147263) answer your question?

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY thank you, that is exactly it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my attempt to close the question as a duplicate failed, I'll post an answer: the statement follows from a general theorem on the continuity of Nemytskii operator, which is stated and proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/829707/).